# Prediction.io Text classification build fails

Tags: scala

Installed Pio on Ubuntu. Installed text classification template, imported data. Upon building, i get some SQL errors (im on Postgres for the record):

> pio build --verbose
>
> [SQL Execution]    INSERT INTO pio_meta_enginemanifests VALUES(
>   'VcGPC4EzkjqEVCYmU1YdLvNyjMkbNa4s',
>   '36dc85cb0d6c0f72434a04756323b01863a36d51', 'PredictionIO-0.9.6',
>   'pio-autogen-manifest',
>   'file:/home/ubuntu/PredictionIO-0.9.6/target/scala-2.10/org.template.textclassification.TextClassific... (276)', ''); (1 ms)
>
> [Stack Trace]
>       ...
>       io.prediction.data.storage.jdbc.JDBCEngineManifests$$anonfun$2.apply(JDBCEngineManifests.scala:48)
>       io.prediction.data.storage.jdbc.JDBCEngineManifests$$anonfun$2.apply(JDBCEngineManifests.scala:40)
>       scalikejdbc.DBConnection$$anonfun$3.apply(DBConnection.scala:297)
>       scalikejdbc.DBConnection$class.scalikejdbc$DBConnection$$rollbackIfThrowable(DBConnection.scala:274)
>       scalikejdbc.DBConnection$class.localTx(DBConnection.scala:295)
>       scalikejdbc.DB.localTx(DB.scala:60)
>       scalikejdbc.DB$.localTx(DB.scala:257)
>       io.prediction.data.storage.jdbc.JDBCEngineManifests.insert(JDBCEngineManifests.scala:40)
>       io.prediction.data.storage.jdbc.JDBCEngineManifests.update(JDBCEngineManifests.scala:89)
>       io.prediction.tools.RegisterEngine$.registerEngine(RegisterEngine.scala:50)
>       io.prediction.tools.console.Console$.build(Console.scala:822)
>       io.prediction.tools.console.Console$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Console.scala:707)
>       io.prediction.tools.console.Console$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Console.scala:693)
>       scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
>       io.prediction.tools.console.Console$.main(Console.scala:693)
>       ...

Any idea? I have followed all of the instructions to be in a "vanilla" state, so i am not sure what's going on.

thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Embarrassingly, actually this is not an error; it's just a confirmation message. So everything is well, you can continue to the next step :-)